# ODBC Connect to Oracle 64bit from MS Access (Using System32\odbcad32.exe)

Tags: ms-access, oracle11g, odbc

I need to connect to a 64 bit Oracle server via ODBC in Microsoft Access. I have installed the 64 Bit ODBC drivers and set up the DSN using the System32\odbcad32 file.

The registry is pointing the driver towards:

C:\app\erahn\product\12.1.0\client_3\SQORA32.DLL

I cannot validate online that SQORA32.DLL is the 64 bit driver; the install package was the 64 bit version so I am assuming that it is.

I did not have luck connecting to the server using the 32 bit drivers either (Test connection would not work), so I am at as loss for what could be holding me back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: Did you get any more specific error message?

Comment: Your ODBC drivers type (32-bit ot 64-bit) have to match your client software (MS Access in your case) not the server's type. If you have 32-bit MS Office then install 32-bit Oracle client.

Comment: List your steps and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the package listed here, which includes 64 Bit Oracle ODBC Drivers: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html  I then opened the ODBCAD32 file in C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe. Under USER DSN, I clicked Add, Selected Oracle in OraClient 12Home3, and hit finish. I then added the connection information which I received from IT and used 'Test Connection' which gave me a successful. In Microsoft Access 2010, I selected 'ODBC Database' from the External Data Ribbon, Linked to Data source, and selected the Machine Data source DSN

Comment: At that point, I receive the "ODBC--Call Failed. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (#0)" error.

Answer (score 4):

I made it work... after 100s of attempts looking everywhere.. This may be of no use to someone.. but if all else fails for you... try it.

I am on Windows 7, 64 Bit.. using Access 64 Bit..

just download these 2 files... from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications
Download instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.2.0.zip (53,669,935 bytes)

*Instant Client Package - ODBC: Additional libraries for enabling ODBC applications
Download instantclient-odbc-windows.x64-11.2.0.2.0.zip (1,356,558 bytes)

Remember download only 11.2.0.2.0  (for me all other version did not work and had numerous issues).

then follow directions from here:

http://celemotan.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/instantclient/

Comment: Absolutely unbelievable. Literally, you need to use **11.2.0.2** packages (you have to merge them before running odbc_install). This client is truly the only one connecting to Access 64-bit. Thank you for the research and saving so much time for others.

Comment: I just stumbled on this post while researching ORA-01406 while connecting to Oracle from MS Access 2013 64-bit.  I followed the instructions (except for downloading the 12.2 version of files to match our database) and they still work like a charm.  Thanks a million! P.S. slight change, I opened a command window and ran odbc_install in order to see the output else the window closed so fast you could not see what the result was.